# WordPress, plugin pods, Ddescargas

Tags: wordpress, descarga, pods, descargar

Estoy trabajando con WordPress y el complemento PODS que te permite crear tipos de publicaciones personalizadas.

En uno de mis CPT hay un campo de archivo creado con PODS que permite cargar archivos pdf y funciona bien. Estos archivos subidos se utilizan, posteriormente, para poder descargar dicho pdf en el FrontEnd.

Recupero, cuando configuro la página para descargas, la URL de ese pdf para descargar a través de un código PODS que es algo así como {mi_archivo} (el nombre del campo entre corchetes). Y aquí viene el problema que no sé cómo solucionar: la descarga se abre en la misma ventana en la que está la página y quiero forzarla o, como mucho, cargarla en _blank, pero no puedo.

He encontrado este código que, parece ser, puede darme la URL del archivo

```
<?php $pod = pods(); echo $pod->display( 'mi_archivo' );
```

Mi idea es añadir a esa URL un atributo download para forzar la descarga en el enlace, pero no sé cómo llegar ahí

¿Puede alguien ayudarme por favor?

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución a mi problema. La comparto por aquí por si puede ayudar a alguien:

1. He prescindido del módulo WYSIWYG para inluir mi enlace
2. He utilizado un módulo de código y, en él, he incluido el siguiente código que funciona perfectamente:

   ```
    <?php $pod = pods();?>
    <p>Descargar documentos adicionales:
    <strong></br><a href="<?php echo $pod->display( 'archivo' ); ?>" download="Documento"> Descargar</a></strong></p>
   ```